# ie ignores flash width/height, display remains small

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

http://img37.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=70261_mov_122_187lo.jpg

how do i stretch the movie to fill the entire white area which is set to be 500 to 350 px (please see pic)

the code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="videos/player.swf" width="500"     height="350">
<param name="movie" value="videos/player.swf">
<param name="quality" value="Best">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
<param name="FlashVars" value="flv=01.flv">
<embed src="videos/player.swf" width="500" height="350" type="application/x-shockwave-    flash" quality="Best" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that player.swf's `Stage.scaleMode` property is set to "noScale". Most embedded players do that so they won't get distorted. They then take care of the actual given size and stretch the UI accordingly in runtime.

Since this player doesn't do that automatically (it appears - *or maybe it does, but something went wrong*), I'm assuming there are some flashVars it supports to stretch to the right size. You'll have to provide more details for a better answer (what player you're using, if it's custom made provide its code, an online example would be nice, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding CSS width and height to it:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="videos/player.swf"
    width="500" height="350"
    style="width:500px;height:350px">
...
```